# Linking images from CSS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image

I want to link an image from CSS to Javascript but my code does not work.

**CSS :**

```
.backImage {

    background-image: url("img/level1.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;

}
```

**Javascript Code :**

```
var x1 = 450;
var y1 = 40;
var speed1 = 5;
var angle1 = 90;
var mod1 = 1;        

var tmp= $("<div>").addClass('backImage');
var src = tmp.css('background-image').match(/[^"][^"]+/g)[1];

console.log(src);

var back = new Image();
    back.src = src;  

function drawBackground() {

    x1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
    y1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x1, y1);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
    context.drawImage(back, -(back.width / 2), -(back.height / 2));
    context.restore();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "link?" Have you tried moving the `context.drawImage(...)` call into an image onload handler? Why do you need to do this at all? It seems like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You mean this(code just updated)

Comment: "but my code does not work" - what doesn't work specifically?  you can't get the filename?  you can't assign it to back.src?  what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to extract an image from the CSS `background-image` source and draw it on canvas. This is how its done.

```js
var tmp = $("<div>").addClass('backImage');
var src = tmp.css('background-image').match(/[^"][^"]+/g)[1];
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

console.log(src);

var back = new Image();
back.src = src;
back.onload = drawBackground;

function drawBackground() {
  canvas.width = back.width;
  canvas.height = back.height;
  context.drawImage(back, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
.backImage {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200/200");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The background is not showing up, heres a fiddle i made: http://jsfiddle.net/jesse_meth/xp8echja/

Comment: But on the fiddle i already have javascript, i dont have to use that.

Comment: @TheGoodGuy - I don't understand. What are you expecting to it to load as background?

Comment: just to get that onto the canvas but load it on javascript

Comment: Yah but theres no image on the canvas

Comment: @TheGoodGuy - [I do see the image on my screen](http://s25.postimg.org/4id3xqdfz/Untitled.png).

Comment: Thats so wierd, i dont see anything on my screen

Comment: @TheGoodGuy - Well, your regex isn't working on Chrome for some reason. It works on Firefox. I'll update the image extraction for it to work on all browsers.

Comment: @TheGoodGuy - [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/xp8echja/6/)! This one will work.